# while using String.Format("{0:n}", 1234) I am getting the output to three decimal places while I require up to two decimal places with comma

Tags: c#, .net

while using String.Format("{0:n}", 1234) I am getting the output to three decimal places while I require up to two decimal places with comma
I am getting the ouput as 1,234.000 in QA environment and 1,234.00 in dev environment for the same code.

Comment: A format string of `"{0:n2}"` will make the decimal places explicit. You should also specify an `IFormatProvider` using an overload which accepts one with a value appropriate to the locale you want to format numbers for (e.g. `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")` or `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`) so that the formatting is consistent regardless of the installed locale of the operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#numeric-format-specifier-n):

> The precision specifier indicates the desired number of digits after the decimal point. **If the precision specifier is omitted, the number of decimal places is defined by the current NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits property.**
>
> **The result string is affected by the formatting information of the current NumberFormatInfo object.** The following table lists the NumberFormatInfo properties that control the formatting of the result string.

Essentially, the thread your code is running in has a culture (`System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`) and that defines a property (`NumberFormat`) and its `NumberDecimalDigits` property sets the default number of decimal places to be used for this culture. Without specifying a culture to use when formatting the number as a string, the thread culture is used.

If you want to force 2 decimal places, you should change your code to this:

```
string result = String.Format("{0:n2}", 1234);
```

Or you could force `String.Format` to use the invariant culture:

```
string result = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:n}", 1234)
```

Comment: Can we also add both and write like this string result = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:n2}", 1234);

Comment: @Pradeep Yes, you can.